# How are we to view Romans 8:1,2, which speaks to a new "spirit of life" in Christ Jesus, in light of Jesus' command in Mark 12:30, to put God first?

Tags: romans, mark, covenant

If the **greatest** commandment is to: Love God with all heart; soul; mind; and strength, as directed by Christ Jesus, in answer to a scribe's question, then what are we to make of Paul's statement, which in effect puts Christ Jesus above all? Aren't both directives part of the "New Covenant"?

> Rom 8:1, 2 (BLB) - Therefore there is now no condemnation to those in
> Christ Jesus. For the Law of the Spirit of life has set you free in
> Christ Jesus from the Law of sin and death.

Comment: FWIW, this looks like [viewpoint swarming](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4011/27581) bait because one easy answer is "Trinitarianism", which is debated. Let's enjoy hermeneutical diligence, keep this open for now, and try to respond without provoking flags. Cheers!

Comment: @Austin - My 3rd comment under Dottard's answer may answer your question. The OT rests on: *"Love God with all your heart, soul, mind and strength and love your neighbor as yourself."* (**Matt, 22:37-40**). *"On these two commandments depend the whole Law and the Prophets."* After the "Cross", however, it would appear that we have two new commandments. (See **1 John 3:23,24, NKJV**)...*And this is His commandment: that we should believe on the name of his son Jesus Christ and love one another .... by the Spirit whom He has given us.* Although I, myself, could do without the trinitarian aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jesus Christ never at any time received "a new spirit of life". That is because, even from creation, Life (with a capital 'L') was already in him. "I am the Way, the Truth, and the Life" he said (John 14:6), while on Earth as the *logos* made flesh, before he died physically. He also said, during his time on Earth, that those who 'partook' of him by faith abide in him, and he in them, and that is how Christians "shall live by me" (John 6:56-57). Then he added:

> "It is the spirit that quickens [enlivens]; the flesh profits nothing;
> the words that I speak unto you, they are spirit and they are life.
> (John 6:63)

Because the words Jesus spoke were the words the Father gave him to speak, nobody can separate the words of the Father from the words of Christ, the Son. That is why John explained that the *logos* [word]  made everything that was made; that without him, nothing was made that was made (John 1:3). John knew Jesus to be the Life, as well as the Light of the world, from before creation. Jesus did not give up being the Life in order to perform his ministry on Earth. He gave up his earthly life to prove that he is the Life that created all life, for Death could not hold him. He triumphed over Death because he always has been, and always will be the Life. Darkness could not triumph over him at Golgotha, because he always has been, and always will be the Light of the world.

Jesus put God first when he was on Earth, as all Christians are to do. By the Spirit of Christ in us, we live spiritually because new life (the new, spiritual, birth of John chapter 3) was given to us in order to let us 'see' just who Jesus really is and so to put total faith in him for life eternal. That is what Romans 8:1-2 is all about. Once the Spirit is received in the new birth we can then stop walking after the flesh and walk after the Spirit:

> "For the law of the Spirit of the life in Christ Jesus hath made me
> free from the law of sin and death... For they that are after the
> flesh do mind the things of the flesh, but they that are after the
> Spirit the things of the Spirit." (Romans 8:1-2 & 4 A.V.)

That accords perfectly with Mark 12:30, as we can see from the way Jesus put that very point, when asked what the greatest commandment was:

> "Thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy heart, and with all thy
> soul, and with all thy mind. This is the first and greatest
> commandment. And the second like unto it, Thou shalt love thy
> neighbour as thyself. On these two commands hang all the law and the
> prophets." Matthew 22:36-40)

Jesus did exactly that. Christians are to do exactly that, and they are enabled because the new spirit of life is now in them. To obey and love Christ utterly is the same as to love and obey God utterly, for no division can be brought between them. The words Jesus speaks are spirit and they are life, because he speaks all the words of the Father, being the *logos*, the word that spoke all life into creation, and which causes the new, spiritual life through faith in Christ. That is God's arrangement. To abide in Christ is to abide in God. To love Christ is to love God, and Jesus promised that all who love him are loved by the Father, and they will make their abode in that person - by the indwelling Spirit.

> "If ye abide in me, and my words abide in you... herein is my Father
> glorified, that ye bear much fruit; so shall ye be my disciples... If
> ye keep my commandments, ye shall abide in my love; even as I have
> kept my Father's commandments, and abide in his love." John 15:7-10
> A.V.

Prior to that, Jesus had said that those who love him keep his commandments, and the Father gives the Spirit to abide with them forever, the Spirit of truth; and "my Father will love him, and we will come unto him, and make our abode with him." (John 14:15-17 & 23) That's how we are to view Romans 8. But if we are not yet born of the Spirit, we cannot view it that way.

Comment: + 1. This and Dottard's answer are good answers, even though you both base your answers on the belief that Jesus, the Son, is also God, and you both can't help but capitalize the (S)pirit, emanating from both, which can't help but speak to yours and his Trinitarianism. How opportune is that, as it conveniently serves to facilitate the answering thereof. The question now I guess is: Which answer does this *non* trinitarian favor? Do I go with the *irrepressible* Dottard, or the *enigmatic* enlightened one .....

Comment: @Olde English, just to say that when I quote from a Bible translation, I use their capitalization, or non-capitalization of Spirit/spirit. But if you put lower-case spirit into the whole of my answer, that makes no difference to the logic of the answer; the logos is the light of life, as in John's prologue. Has been since time began, and always will be to all eternity. It is "life eternal" that he is, and that he gives. That is what facilitates my answer. On, and thanks!

Comment: *no difference to the logic of the answer*, aside, the "NWT of the HS" never capitalizes 'spirit', as the trans' is not biased towards Trinitarianism, whereas the same cannot be said for most other trans', which IMO is one of the great 'unfortunates'. I try to remember to utilize a disclaimer when quoting from the likes of the NASB - like I did in 'comment' here under my Q. Then there is my penultimate comment, under JB's A., which I would respectfully suggest you now take note of. Also, seeing as you yourself brought up John chapter 3, I would now point you to its 18th v. On, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is given in John 1.

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
> was God. He was with God in the beginning. Through Him all things were
> made, and without Him nothing was made that has been made. **In Him
> was life, and that life was the light of men.**

This is reinforced in Rom 8:9-11 when Paul says:

> You, however, are controlled not by the flesh, but by the Spirit, if
> the Spirit of God lives in you. And if anyone does not have the
> **Spirit of Christ**, he does not belong to Christ. But if Christ is in you, your body is dead because of sin, yet your spirit is alive
> because of righteousness. And if the Spirit of Him who raised Jesus
> from the dead is living in you, He who raised Christ Jesus from the
> dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit, who
> lives in you.

Thus, the Spirit is called the Spirit of Christ who lives in us to make us what we are not - Christians who reflect and imitate the life of Christ.

To put this another way, Jesus said He will send the Holy Spirit to guide us (John 16:13).  Without the Spirit of Christ we cannot be Christian, we cannot love.  John expresses it this way:

> 1 John 4:11-13 - Beloved, if God so loved us, we also ought to love
> one another. No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God
> remains in us, and His love is perfected in us. By this we know that
> we remain in Him, and He in us: He has given us of His Spirit.
>
> 1 John 4:17-19 - In this way, love has been perfected among us, so
> that we may have confidence on the day of judgment; for in this world
> we are just like Him. There is no fear in love, but perfect love
> drives out fear, because fear involves punishment. The one who fears
> has not been perfected in love. We love because He first loved us.

Thus, we must put God first in order to love at all.  That is the essence of the Covenant - to love God supremely because He first loved us.  This is keynote of the Book of Deuteronomy as stated in the Shema (which Jesus quoted) -

> Deut 6:4, 5 - Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is One. And
> you shall love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your
> soul and with all your strength.

Comment: I had intended for this Q of mine to be more of a "covenantal " question. I, myself, see Jesus' own words, in Mark's verse, as possibly being in respect of the "Old (Mosaic) Covenant" and Paul's vv. (after the cross) to be in respect of the "New Covenant". I guess it was a kind of a *"gotcha"* Q, although I hadn't really intended for it to be that way. I certainly hadn't intended to invoke "Trinitarian" thoughts, but on reflection I guess that was inevitable.

Comment: Whilst we have always differed as to the actual meaning of **John 1:1c**, your answer carried much weight and is therefore worthy of an upvote for content. Your last edit was done just before I got my initial comment out. It is my hope that you will consider editing further, now that you can see what I was *truly* contemplating, or, at the very least, comment on same.

Comment: With all due respect, your further edit is all very well as it pertains to the OC, but I'm more concerned with the NC, where the *love* of Jesus is **paramount**, to the receiving of the "spirit of life", which is not to *impugn* God, Himself. It's just that Jesus, by way of his sacrifice, came to be the **full** embodiment of the law, he having in effect *nailed* the "Mosaic Law", at least as it pertains to "sin", to the cross, which (sacrifice) is actually in glorification of God, when all is said and done, to the betterment of mankind.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - that is a very subtle distinction that I am not sure that the Scripture make.  It is the love of God that allowed Jesus to be offered at Calvary as the ultimate expression of God's grace.  And, because God loved us, we love Him and the brethren.

Comment: Well at least you're not sure. I'll take that, for now.

Comment: @OldeEnglish Friend, the covenantal aspect that you seek in an answer is this: that we love YHWH our God through putting on the body of Jesus in this new covenant. We put on the body of Christ by believing in his resurrection and following him by keeping his superior commandments in the Spirit, which was installed into our bodies by belief (Ephesians 1)

Comment: @OldeEnglish - oops - I wrote "key not" which should have been "keynote".  Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The Spirit of life proceeds only from the Father God (but it does not proceed from the Jesus the Son as he is not God!).

The Son, as our interceding High Priest at the right hand of the Father God, asks the Father for the Spirit to be given within you by belief and petition, because the Son is within you by faith, and then the Father responds by sending you the Spirit of life.

The Spirit of Christ is the Spirit of God, because the Holy Spirit was what made Christ sinless from birth, as he was "born of the Spirit" from the onset.

**Conclusion**: The new Spirit of life is the Holy Spirit which proceeds from the Father God alone, as he is the source of all spirits and the Holy Spirit itself.

Nevertheless, we cannot come to the Father God unless we put on the body of Christ, whom God sent for us to atone for our sin, whereby in his name we can wash the temple of our bodies clean of lawlessness which is paramount for the insertion of God's Holy Spirit that seals us for eternal life.

Comment: John 1:1 - says that Jesus is God and so does Titus 2:13, 2 peter 1:1, Phil 2:5, etc.  This answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: John 1:1 says, "and a god (divine) was the Word." Titus 2:13 says, "the appearing of the Glory of our great God, the Savior Jesus Christ." etc.

Comment: That is grammatically wrong!  "Logos" has the article and so is the subject and NOT the object and thus we must translate, "The Word was God".  This is a simple Greek logic category statement. To reinforce this, look at all the other texts just quoted such as Heb 1:8, 9 where the Father even calls Jesus "The God". (Ho Theos)  But this is not the place to debate as these questions have been raised many times before.

Comment: Again, your answer is factually incorrect as the Holy Spirit is also called the "Spirit of Christ" as per Rom 8:9, 1 Peter 1:11, Phil 1:19, etc.  Please check your facts!

Comment: That is an unscriptural assumption of yours for which there is no evidence.  Jesus was God as declared numerous times in the NT.

Comment: @Dottard Yes, the Holy Spirit is also the Spirit of Christ. And this is so because the Holy Spirit of God was fully within the person of Jesus Christ, who was the human incarnation of the Angel of YHWH, the firstborn of creation and the only Son of God.

Comment: You are awfully *emphatic* for a New Contributor. Have you ever thought to use IMO? The Son may not be God, but being the "only begotten" of God, and not therefore *made*, his inheritance speaks to a divinity of his own. Consequently, the "spirit of life" can be obtained directly from either (G)od, Himself, or from the *lessor* (g)od, Jesus. With regard to your last paragraph, we do have to believe in Jesus' "Ransom Sacrifice", as being an atonement for our sins, in order to be *filled* with the aforementioned "spirit of life".

Comment: As regards the latter part of my Q., I'm afraid you have not, yet at least, addressed that "covenantal" aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Without the “Law of Spirit”, i.e. the orderly activity in us of the uncreated divine Spirit who proceeds from the Father, and without the incarnate Logos, Jesus Christ, whose divinity is revealed to us by the same Spirit (1 Cor. 12:3), it is absolutely impossible to love God the Father, for love of God-Father analytically entails love of the Son and the Spirit through whom and only through whom the love of God-the Father can be communicated to us.

How, in fact, can we admire the sun for providing us suntan unless co-loving the sun-rays through which this tan is affected on our bodies?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151171/discussion-on-answer-by-levan-gigineishvili-how-are-we-to-view-romans-81-2-whi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

It may help to realize that we are not under God's "new covenant".  The new covenant will be established with Israel when Christ returns to earth for His millennial reign.  All believers today (both Jew and Gentile) are under God's grace, not covenant:

Ephesians 3:2

> If ye have heard of the dispensation of the grace of God which is given me to you-ward:

Hebrews 8:8

> For finding fault with them, he saith, Behold, the days come, saith the Lord, when I will make a new covenant with the house of Israel and with the house of Judah:

Romans 6:14

> For sin shall not have dominion over you: for ye are not under the law, but under grace.

Ephesians 2:12

> That at that time ye were without Christ, being aliens from the commonwealth of Israel, and strangers from the covenants of promise, having no hope, and without God in the world:

Consider that we are to follow the heavenly ministry of Christ ascended through Paul, not His earthly ministry through the twelve for Israel:

Romans 15:8

> Now I say that Jesus Christ was a minister of the circumcision for the truth of God, to confirm the promises made unto the fathers:

Matthew 10:5-6

> These twelve Jesus sent forth, and commanded them, saying, Go not into the way of the Gentiles, and into any city of the Samaritans enter ye not:
> 6 But go rather to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.

Matthew 15:24

> But he answered and said, I am not sent but unto the lost sheep of the house of Israel.

John 4:22

> Ye worship ye know not what: we know what we worship: for salvation is of the Jews.

Acts 11:19

> Now they which were scattered abroad upon the persecution that arose about Stephen travelled as far as Phenice, and Cyprus, and Antioch, preaching the word to none but unto the Jews only.

2 Corinthians 5:14-16

> For the love of Christ constraineth us; because we thus judge, that if one died for all, then were all dead:
> 15 And that he died for all, that they which live should not henceforth live unto themselves, but unto him which died for them, and rose again.
> 16 Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more.

It is for this reason that Christ's commandments to Israel prior to His death, burial, and resurrection do not coincide with Paul's gospel of God's grace and Christ crucified.

1 Corinthians 15:1-4

> <sup>**1**</sup> Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand; <sup>**2**</sup> By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain. <sup>**3**</sup> For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures; <sup>**4**</sup> And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

Yes, God remains the same, but His instructions to mankind changed when Christ's blood was shed for all humanity.  It is now about having faith in Jesus Christ and what He alone **completed** for us at the cross.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151225/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-vestal-how-are-we-to-view-romans-81-2-which-speak); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.